# jQuery ajax form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I tried many ways to create a simple jquery ajax form but don't know why it is not submitting and/or returning the notification.

Here is my code:

**Javascript**

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery1.11/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
...

$('#form_signup').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'signup.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#form_signup_text').html(data.msg);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#form_signup_text').html(data.msg);
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="form_signup" name="form_signup" method="POST">
    <div>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail1" name="inputEmail1" placeholder="your@email.com">
    </div>
    <div>
        <a type="submit">Sign up!</a>
    </div>
    <div id="form_signup_text">
        <!-- A fantastic notice will be placed here =D -->
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$our_mail =    "our@email.com";
$subject  =    "Wohoo! A new signup!";
$email    =    $_POST['inputEmail1'];

$return = array();
$return['msg'] = 'Thank you!';
$return['error'] = false;

if(preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)){

    $message = "Yesss!! We receive a new signup!
    E-mail: $email
    ";
    mail($our_mail, $subject, $message);

}
else {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] .= 'Something is wrong... snifff...';
}

return json_encode($return);
```

---

**Solved:**

There were three problems. And different users solve each of these problems.

1. In PHP, you must "echo" the return array instead of "return"
2. At first, you should use a submit button instead of an anchor in the form
3. In the input, you must set both "id" and "name"

If any of these users want, you can edit or add a new answer with these details, and the points are yours.

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Comment: `<input type="email" id="inputEmail1" name="inputEmail1" placeholder="your@email.com">` name attribute must be there in order to get the value on server.

Comment: Kevin B, you were right from the start. The correct way is to use a submit button.

Comment: Amit, you are right. I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do 3 things.

**First**, wrap your jQuery codes inside **`$(document).ready()`** function,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#form_signup').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'signup.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#form_signup_text').html(data.msg);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#form_signup_text').html(data.msg);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Second**, Add a submit button to your form. Also you are missing the **`name`** attribute for the email input field. That causes the error in the php file.

```
<form id="form_signup" name="form_signup" method="POST">
    <div>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail1" name="inputEmail1" placeholder="your@email.com">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Sign Up!"/>
    </div>
    <div id="form_signup_text">
        <!-- A fantastic notice will be placed here =D -->
    </div>
</form>
```

**Third**, **`echo`** the results since you are using AJAX to submit the form. **`return`** will not have any effects.

```
<?php

$our_mail =    "our@email.com";
$subject  =    "Wohoo! A new signup!";
$email    =    $_POST['inputEmail1'];

$return = array();
$return['msg'] = 'Thank you!';
$return['error'] = false;

if(preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)){

    $message = "Yesss!! We receive a new signup!
    E-mail: $email
    ";
    mail($our_mail, $subject, $message);
}
else {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] .= 'Something is wrong... snifff...';
}

echo json_encode($return);exit;
```

I checked and it's working fine.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: the email isn't making it to the server, fyi

Comment: @KevinB, Updated the answer, name attribute was missing in his code.

Comment: There were three problems (see note in question). And different users solve each of these problems. If you want, you can edit or add a new answer with these details, and the points are yours.

Comment: I didn't note that you had a problem with the php. Updated the answer.

Comment: You and rm-vanda have answered all the points, and your question is the most complete and detailed (at the moment). So, the points are yours. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your form.

```
<form id="form_signup" name="form_signup" method="POST">
    <div>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail1" name="inputEmail1" placeholder="your@email.com">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
    <div id="form_signup_text">
        <!-- A fantastic notice will be placed here =D -->
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Exactly. The problem is the use of an anchor. Using a submit button and the problem is solved.

Comment: There were three problems (see note in question). And different users solve each of these problems. If you want, you can edit or add a new answer with these details, and the points are yours.

Answer (score 1):

The php code needs to echo instead of return.

just like this:

`echo json_encode($return);`

Also, your form needs a submit button  - `type="submit"` on an `<a>` tag doesn't trigger the browser's functionality for handling `<form>`s

Finally, you need to ensure that your special submit handler is loaded at just the right time -- which, if it is included at the bottom of the page, right before the footer, it should be just fine. However, you can ensure this by wrapping it in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //[...]
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! You solved one of the two problems. Yes, the correct way is to use "echo" instead of "return"

Comment: There were three problems (see note in question). And different users solve each of these problems. If you want, you can edit or add a new answer with these details, and the points are yours.

Comment: Thanks - ! I appreciate that. Also, for future reference, you might enjoy using alajax -- its a handy, tiny plugin for simplifying this.

Comment: rm-vanda, thank you for your help (and all the others). Since you and IJas have answered all the problems, I have to give the points based on the most detailed answer. And IJas made an excellent work for everyone, but I want to thank you again for all your help, too!

Answer (score 1):

doesn't your a `type="submit"` need to be an input instead?  or a button

Comment: Exactly. The problem is the use of an anchor. Using a submit button and the problem is solved.

Comment: There were three problems (see note in question). And different users solve each of these problems. If you want, you can edit or add a new answer with these details, and the points are yours.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to call webmethod in a ajax using jquery in asp.net, but sometimes it works well and sometimes it doesn't.

Here is my ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "frmTest.aspx/fncSave", 
    data: "{}"
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: "false",
    cache: "false", //True or False
    success: function (response) 
    result = response.d;
    if (result != "") {
        alert(response);
    }
},
Error: function (x, e) {
    alert("err");
    return false;
}
});
```

Here My Server Side Code :

```
<WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function fncSave() As String
    Dim sResult As Int16
    Try
        Dim obj As New ClsCommon()
        sResult = obj.Save()
    Catch ex As Exception
                ex.Message.ToString()
    End Try
    Return sResult
End Function
```

Comment: I recommend you to open a new question. What you specified above is not an answer and is not related to the original question of this link, but it is a new case.

Answer (score -3):

$(this) in the "ajax" function is not the form.
So just try:

```
$('#form_signup').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'signup.php',
        data: $this.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#form_signup_text').html(data.msg);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#form_signup_text').html(data.msg);
        }
    });
});
```

I admit i didn't check the rest of the code, im pretty sure thats the problem.

Of course if the problem still goes, just "f12" and check console and network for server request and headers, make sure all the params are there.

Hope that helped

Comment: That is incorrect. `this` is the form until you get into the success and error callbacks.