# .ajax Only executes on page reload (it is trying to load the URL before doing anything else)

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have a basic Ajax request (see below), but it only executes on page refresh.

When I am debugging this in Chrome the breakpoint is not hit for the onclick event until the page is refreshed, I understand this is because [the page is waiting on something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742117/jquery-code-only-works-on-page-refresh), but if you look in the sources tab it is waiting for a response or something from the URL being requested - even though the actual function hasn't run yet. This only appears in the sources tab once you click the button. Why is it waiting on the URL (which is an IP address, it sends data to the local program) being "called" before the function is even hit? How do I stop it doing this "check"?

[image: Screenshot of network waterfall showing the page is waiting on the ip address as the URL]

```
$("#gt").click(function() {
  $.post({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:13000',
    data: {
      'mediaType': 'giftTag',
      'giftTagMessage': 'Enjoy!'
    },
    success: function(json) {
      alert(json);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
        this.tryCount++;
        if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
          //try again
          $.ajax(this);
          return;
        }
        return;
      }
      if (xhr.status == 500) {
        //handle error
      } else {
        //handle error
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I know there are a number of [[(solved) jQuery ajax form doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180407/solved-jquery-ajax-form-doesnt-work) similar requests], but no quite the same. None deal with the issue of AJAX calling the page preemptively.

Comment: On which port is your UI running?

Comment: It listens on port 13000? Is that what to mean?

Comment: Are you sure that the address `http://127.0.0.1:13000` supports POST requests? Can you try POSTing to this address via Postman or any other REST API testing utilities?

Comment: It does work once I refresh the page, I get the data correctly. I did just try it on port 80 but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not caused by the AJAX itself, it was the other program not writing anything back to the stream quickly enough.